# In Hartl tutorial 10.20, can't "rake db:"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm using Mike Hartl's Rails tutorial, trying to do the following commands:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:reset
$ bundle exec rake db:populate
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

I got the error:

```
sample_app/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:25: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I think I'm mixing up were I put the `end` on my code for the lib/tasks/sample_data.rake file.

Here is the code:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    admin = User.create!(name: "Example User",
                         email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                         password: "foobar",
                         password_confirmation: "foobar",
                         admin: true)
    users = User.all(limit: 6)
    50.times do
      content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
      users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }

    99.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password  = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
    end
  end
end
```

I got a little mixed up, and I'm not great with Ruby code. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `50.times do` block doesn't have an `end`.

It should be:

```
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an "end" missing in the example given in the book. It needs two "end" commands, not one like has been published! The rake takes ages so expect to have to wait a bit.